# Unchomping a file, then appending a string

Tags: ruby, file, chomp

I have a text file with path name `file`, and some content `string` that I want to append to it. I want to do something close to

```
File.open(file, "a"){|io| io.puts(string)}
```

but if the original content of the file does not end with an endline character `$/`, I want to insert one before `string`. What is the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open(file, 'r+') do |f|
  unless (last = f.readlines[-1]) && last.end_with?($/)
    f.puts $/
  end

  f.puts string
end
```

Comment: I though that an answer would look like this, but didn't have in mind of using the `r+` mode.

Answer (score -2):

```
File.open(file, "a"){ |io| 
   io.puts
   io.puts(string)
}
```

Comment: That will add an endline character even when the original content ends with an endline character.

Comment: Then you have to read the last line in the file and if it is empty add an endline character

Comment: Whether the last line is empty does not matter.